# Web-to-Lead from my Wordpress website

Tags: web2lead, wordpress

I had configured the Web-to-Lead in Salesforce and now I need to connect it with my WordPress website.
Is there any plugin to help me with that?
Please note that the edition of Saleforce org is Professional

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing is the API in Pro Edition, that you need to purchase separately. You can try start using standard web-to-lead functionality (available in Pro edition) see: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.setting_up_web-to-lead.htm&type=5 (simply embed the form in the Wordpress) or purchase API and use one of the existing plugins https://www.salesforce.org/blog/integrating-wordpress-salesforce/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your detailed answer!